# How do I install a package that depends on another package that "target projects"?

Tags: yeoman, chocolatey

I am having trouble setting up yeoman. I keep getting this error when trying to install certain packages (yeoman, compass). While, other packages install fine (git, python).

> External packages cannot depend on packages that target projects

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where the failure is, but nuget has a long standing issue that chocolatey also gets with using a content folder :(.

If any package that is depended on has a content folder, it requires the upstream package to also have a content folder. This is undesirable, so the fix is to ask the package maintainer to remove the content folder.